# Send SNS message via Cloudformation/lambda for updating security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I'm attempting to "populate" a SG that is attached to my ALB to allow traffic from Cloudfront in.

This ALB/CF dist are being created via Cloudformation. I currently have a Lambda function that processes SNS messages from AmazonIpSpaceChanged. However, when I create this CF stack that SNS message needs to be fired to populate the SG initially.

Is there a way to create an SNS message to trigger this Lambda function? I looked at SNS backed custom resources but that did not appear to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also personally faced this problem. I was unable to get my SNS topic working to trigger the lambda function. However, I was able to do it with custom resources.

Whenever a lambda function is associated with a custom resource in CloudFormation template, it is invoked during the creation of that custom resource. You will have to depend it on the cloudformation resource that has the code in it, because it wont work if it will fire before the lambda function has been created.

[This is a link to the custom resource documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)

Comment: I am currently doing this. I'm creating a Custom Resource with a lambda backed function that uses python to GET the ip-ranges.json file and then update SGs with that retrieved list. 

HOWEVER, I would prefer to do this a different way because that lambda function is nearly a duplicate of another lambda function that listens to SNS messages from AWS for AmazonIpSpaceChanged.

Comment: Well all of your possibilities are listed here already, you can pick your poison out of them, each one has their own downsides to them

EDIT: All possibilities that I am aware of, at least

Comment: That's sort of what I'm worried about. It's odd though because there's an SNS backed Custom Resource that I was hoping would accomplish this but for the life of me I cannot find good documentation on it nor examples.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the rule to the security group directly from CloudFormation with [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html)?

```
  InboundRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 0
      ToPort: 65535
      SourceSecurityGroupId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - XX_NEW_SECURITY_GROUP_XX
        - GroupId
      GroupId: sg-XX_EXISTING_GROUP_XX
```

Comment: I don't know the IP ranges until after I've sent a GET request to AWS to pull down the ip-ranges.json file.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could use is the notification feature the CloudFormation API offers: When calling [`UpdateStack`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateStack.html) you can provide a list of `NotificationARNs`, which is a list of SNS topics which get notified about every CloudFormation-related change to your stack. You could set the notification SNS topic to the SNS topic you subscribed your AWS Lambda function to. This of course only works if you don't create the SNS topic as part of your CloudFormation stack, you don't rely on the content on the SNS message and just need such a message as trigger and if you filter the SNS messages in your Lambda function to only react to messages which matter to you (like doing updates only on stack creation and not on stack deletion).

Using the AWS CLI and its [`deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) command, specifying a notification ARN would look like:

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --template-file your-template.yaml \
  --stack-name your-stack \
  --notification-arns arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890123456:yourtopic
```

Comment: I thought about this route but it's essentially a "manual" step in the process of bringing up an environment from scratch.